# How to open a cv.DMatchVector object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, opencv, object, attributes, brute-force

I want to compare 2 cv.Mat ("des" and "newObj") objects using cv.BFMatcher in JavaScript. It looks like it works because I see that the length of the "matches" variable. It is 500 after the matching. However, when I try to filter good matches according to the distance I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distance' of undefined
```

My code:

```
var bf = new cv.BFMatcher();
var matches = new cv.DMatchVector();
bf.match(des, newObj, matches);
console.log(matches.size()); // 500

var good_matches = new cv.DMatchVector();
for (let i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    if(matches[i].distance < 40) {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    } 
}
console.log(good_matches.size())
```

Type of the "matches" - object. But I cannot check the keys to find a proper name for the "distance" attribute.

I will be very happy if someone can help me with this issue. Thank you in advance. =)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. Try using:

```
for (let i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
if(matches.get(i).distance < 40) {
    good_matches.push_back(matches.get(i));
}
```

}